# How to integrate 3 database tables in sql using springboot

Tags: sql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I am creating the admin page for mobile recharge website using spring boot and SQL for backend. I have created separate tables for storing plans of prepaid, postpaid and add-ons. Now I would like to integrate all the three tables.

That is, when I enter (/prepaid) URL it should show the data of prepaid table, when I enter (/postpaid) URL it should show the data of postpaid table and like the same for add-ons. I don't have any idea about integration. Can anyone share some example or give some idea about it

[Github link for code.](https://github.com/keerthi-senthil/prepaid/tree/main/admin-backend)  This the spring boot code for prepaid. Like the same I have done for postpaid and add-on. Kindly refer the code and share your ideas

Answer (score 0):

It will also work the same way as u are handling your `Admin`.

**Note**: Basically u need Model for every table and repository for each Model.

**Model**

```
@Table(name = "prepaid")
public class Prepaid implements Serializable{
   /*all fields here*/
   /*Getter and Setter*/
}
@Table(name = "postpaid")
public class Postpaid implements Serializable{
   /*all fields here*/
   /*Getter and Setter*/
}
@Table(name = "addon") //<--necessary in all model
public class Addons implements Serializable{
   /*all fields here*/
   /*Getter and Setter*/
}
```

**Repository**

```
public interface PrepaidRepo extends JpaRepository<Prepaid,Long> {
   /*all functions here*/
}
public interface PostpaidRepo extends JpaRepository<Postpaid,Long> {
   /*all functions here*/
}
public interface AddonRepo extends JpaRepository<Addon,Long> {
   /*all functions here*/
}
```

**Service**

```
public class PostpaidService{
  PostpaidRepo postpaid;
  /*handling functions*/
}
public class PrepaidService{
  PrepaidRepo prepaid;
  /*handling functions*/
}
public class AddonService{
  AddonRepo addon;
  /*handling functions*/
}
```

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping("/prepaid-plan")
public class PrepaidController{
  /*route handling functions*/
}
@RequestMapping("/postpaid-plan")
public class PostpaidController{
  /*route handling functions*/
}
@RequestMapping("/addon-plan")
public class AddonController{
  /*route handling functions*/
}
```